# What prevents data from being inserted in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert

I have set the CI framework with database connection, put it on autoload and created a form, yet still, nothing is inserted into the Database!

I've tried using objects(classes) and different ways to pass information in an array

```php
if (isset($_POST['register-submit'])) {

$this->load->model('Registermodel');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('register-username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('register-password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('register-password-repeat', 'confirm passphrase', 'required|min_length[6]|matches[register-password]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('register-pin', 'pin', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{6}$/]');

//If form validation was successful
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

  echo 'successfully registered!';

  //Add user to database
  $data = array(
    'ci_useruniqid'=> $_POST['register-uniqid'],
    'ci_userdate'=> $_POST['register-date'],
    'ci_useruid'=>  $_POST['register-username'],
    'ci_userpwd'=>  password_hash($_POST['register-password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
    'ci_usermnemonic'=> $_POST['register-mnemonic'],
    'ci_usercurrentaddress'=> $_POST['register-address'],
    'ci_useraccount'=>  $_POST['register-account'],
    'ci_useraccountbalance'=> $_POST['register-account-balance'],
    'ci_userpin'=>  $_POST['register-pin'],
    'ci_userstatus'=> $_POST['register-status'],
    'ci_usertype'=> $_POST['register-type'],
    'ci_userinfo'=> $_POST['register-info'],
    'ci_userpgp'=>  $_POST['register-pgp'],
    'ci_usercurrency'=> $_POST['register-currency']
  );
  $this->RegisterModel->adduser($data);

  redirect("AuthController/loginview", "refresh");
}
```

What I expect to happen is for the data(as seen above) to be inserted into the DB. My actual result is no response even something as simple as echoing something out in an if statement.

My table structure:

```
ci_userid   int(11)
ci_useruniqid   
ci_userdate date
ci_useruid  
ci_userpwd  
ci_usermnemonic 
ci_usercurrentaddress   
ci_useraccount  
ci_useraccountbalance   decimal(12,8)
ci_userpin  
ci_userstatus   
ci_usertype 
ci_userinfo 
ci_userpgp  
ci_usercurrency
```

The rest are text, here is my `adduser` model:

```
  public function adduser($data) {



$insert = $this->db->insert('users', $data);

  }
```

Comment: Can you show your code of `adduser` function of `RegisterModel` file? Also show the table SS.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute!

Comment: Just FYI, if you name your form inputs that have the data to be inserted like `name="data[ci_useruniqid]"` then your code would just be `$this->RegisterModel->adduser($_POST['data']);`

Comment: If you can't echo something from an if statement, the assumption is that it's not true. Have you checked for PHP errors in your logs?

Comment: @miken32 I'm aware of that, I've tried different ones with both `else` and `else if` statements, both show nothing.

Comment: Then you're likely getting a parse error somewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: You can print last executed query after `$this->RegisterModel->adduser($data);` using `echo $this->db->last_query();` check this query and run directly in mysql. Check if there is any error.

Comment: @RohitMittal it won't echo out anything.

Comment: Then you need to debug your code on every line. You can try to do die with comment just after if condition and check if code is reachable at that point. You need to further use this for complete code.

Comment: It won't even die when I tell it to when I press the button!

Comment: Could we see all the code for the controller, please? There might be something you didn't share that affects the results.

Comment: troubleshooting in CI 101: (1) enabled `db_debug` in `database.php`, (2) make sure prod environment in `index.php` is set to development (to enable error reporting), (3) comment or remove *redirects*. Then try your code again, if it is still blank add an echo at the beginning of the controller function. If you still can't see it, idk what to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this was too long for a comment, I present to you my quasi answer that will help you debug.

```
echo 'hello world <br><pre>';
        print_r($_POST);

        if (isset($_POST['register-submit'])) {

            $this->load->model('Registermodel');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('register-username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('register-password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('register-password-repeat', 'confirm passphrase', 'required|min_length[6]|matches[register-password]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('register-pin', 'pin', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{6}$/]');

//If form validation was successful
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                echo 'successfully registered!';

//Add user to database
                $data = array(
                    'ci_useruniqid' => $_POST['register-uniqid'],
                    'ci_userdate' => $_POST['register-date'],
                    'ci_useruid' => $_POST['register-username'],
                    'ci_userpwd' => password_hash($_POST['register-password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                    'ci_usermnemonic' => $_POST['register-mnemonic'],
                    'ci_usercurrentaddress' => $_POST['register-address'],
                    'ci_useraccount' => $_POST['register-account'],
                    'ci_useraccountbalance' => $_POST['register-account-balance'],
                    'ci_userpin' => $_POST['register-pin'],
                    'ci_userstatus' => $_POST['register-status'],
                    'ci_usertype' => $_POST['register-type'],
                    'ci_userinfo' => $_POST['register-info'],
                    'ci_userpgp' => $_POST['register-pgp'],
                    'ci_usercurrency' => $_POST['register-currency']
                );
                $this->RegisterModel->adduser($data);
                echo 'success';
                //redirect("AuthController/loginview", "refresh");
            } else {
                echo validation_errors();
            }
        } else {
            echo 'register-submit... well... does not exist';
        }
```

Please note, use `$this->input->post('somename');` for all your `$_POST` stuff. e.g. assume that `register-uniqid` doesn't exist (form validation won't catch it because it isn't required) you'll get an undefined index error; thus you'd have to do `isset($_POST['register-uniqid']) ? $_POST['register-uniqid'] : null` whereas `$this->input->post()` does that logic for you.

Now, even if you make this fix, if `register-uniqid` is absolutely critical (cannot be null) then make sure form validation covers it with a required. Even though you may have some hidden fields, it doesn't mean the user can't delete them if they want and post a null to that db column. I would suggest forgoing hidden fields entirely and coding any *non-user-related* input in to this controller or model.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to CI and one of the things I thought was going to be easier was debugging, glad I asked this question :-)

Comment: Another thing, every time I reload it inserts again, why?

Comment: typically: form submits to a processor and the processor either redirects back to the form on a failure, or to a success page. the form and processor and success page can be integrated, but that does not appear to be what you have. you need the redirect to solve your loop and bear in mind that given your scheme, you'll have to use flash messages (or change to ajax or a 1 pager) to get your *expected* error messages e.g. form validation. and for future "not working" is never a good starting point - it shows a lack of troubleshooting and is generally downvoted.